# Kotlin Dynamic Array implementation with generics

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, data-structures

I'm learning data structures and trying to implement a dynamic array from scratch in Kotlin using generics. I came up with the following implementation using a MutableList but that feels like cheating . Am I doing this correctly or is there another/better way that allows me to learn by implementing the individual operations manually? What's the usual way others go about this?

```
class DynamicArray<T>(
    private var values: MutableList<T>
) {
    var length: Int = values.size
        private set
    var isEmpty: Boolean = length > 0
        private set

    fun getValues() = values

    // O(1) time complexity
    fun lookup(index: Int) = values[index]

    // O(1) time complexity
    fun push(item: T): MutableList<T> {
        values.add(length, item)
        length++
        return values
    }

    // O(n) time complexity because we have to shift remaining items
    fun remove(item: T): MutableList<T> {
        values.remove(item)
        length--
        return values
    }
}
```

Comment: `MutableList` is already dynamic, so yes, kinda cheating. Try using simple `Array` where you would need to re-create new arrays based on size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically you're saying that in order for your `DynamicArray` to exist, you need an already implemented mutable list (dynamic array) structure to rely upon.

So if you're trying to learn how these data structures are made, you should try to make one instead of using one. At the moment you're just delegating the difficult parts to someone else's work.

Try implementing this using only the `Array` type to make an `ArrayList` style implementation, or try not using an `Array` at all to implement a `LinkedList` type structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick implementation that uses `Array` as the underlying DS.
It implements a `MutableIterable` which is basically an `Iterable` that also allows you to remove an element while iterating.

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class DynamicArray<T>(
    private var size: Int,
    private val expansionFactor: Float = 2f,
    private val init: (Int) -> T) : MutableIterable<T> {

    var capacity: Int = size
        private set

    private var arr: Array<Any?> = Array(size, init)

    inner class DynamicArrayIterator: MutableIterator<T>{
        val iterator = arr.iterator()
        var index = -1

        override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
            return index<size-1
        }

        override fun next(): T {
            if(iterator.hasNext()) index++
            else throw NoSuchElementException()
            return iterator.next() as T
        }

        override fun remove() {
            removeAt(index--)
        }

    }

    override fun iterator(): MutableIterator<T> = DynamicArrayIterator()

    fun size(): Int = size

    //O(1)
    fun get(index: Int): T {
        if(index > size-1) throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
        return arr[index] as T
    }

    //O(1)
    fun set(index: Int, element: T) {
        if(index > size-1) throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()

        arr[index] = element
    }

    //O(1) amortized
    fun add(element: T){
        if(size == capacity){
            capacity = (expansionFactor*size).toInt()
            val newArr = Array<Any?>(capacity, init = init)
            arr.forEachIndexed { index, any -> newArr[index] = any as T }

            arr = newArr
        }

        arr[size] = element
        size++
    }

    //O(n)
    fun removeAt(index: Int): T{
        if(index > size-1) throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
        val element = arr[index] as T

        for( i in index until size){
            arr[i] = arr[i+1]
        }

        size--

        return element
    }

    //O(n)
    fun remove(element: T): Boolean{

        for(i in 0 until size){
            if(arr[i] == element) {
                removeAt(i)
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    //O(n)
    override fun toString(): String {
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        stringBuilder.append("[")
        var index = 0
        do{
            if (index in 1 until size)
                stringBuilder.append(", ")
            stringBuilder.append(arr[index])

            index++
        } while (index < size)
        return stringBuilder.append("]").toString()
    }
}
```